# VBA extracting only select info between <div> tags

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to check if the html tag:

```
<nobr>Target</nobr>
```

exists on the page, and if it does, search for the text between the html tag:

```
<div style='width: 555px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;> ... </div>
```

The text between the div tags look messy like:

```
ABC [HSA: 
<a href="...">...</a>
] [KO:
<a href="...">...</a>
]
<br />
GHI-JK [JKI:
...
```

And I want to get and print to my spreadsheet however many items there are, but I only want the item name (in the above example, there're 2 items - ABC and GHI-JK).

Of course my code below doesn't work., I don't think I'm using queryselector correctly and I'm also not sure how to only grab the item names, instead of the entirety between the  tags

```
If IE.document.querySelector("nobr").innerHTML = "Target" Then
    If IE.document.querySelector("div[style^='width: 555px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;']") <> 0 Then
         Cells(1, 15).Value = IE.document.querySelector("div[style^='width: 555px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;']").innerText
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Please show more of the HTML and the URL if possible and explain exactly what data you are expecting to see retrieved. Use actual HTML as is rather than any shorthanding and please use the snippet tool to add the HTML as code  not an image

Comment: @QHarr Added the link and the entire block of html code I'm interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector combination to target the element of interest.

The data is in a `div`, that is inside an element with class `td51`.

[image: class]

You can write a CSS selector combination to target this pattern of:

```
.td51 div
```

This says elements with `div` tag whose parent is `td51` class. Where `"."` is a class selector.

The element space element pattern is known as a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

---

**CSS query results:**

This pattern matches multiple elements and you want the item as index 6.

[image: query]

As multiple items are retrieved you use the `querySelectorAll` to apply the CSS combinator and retrieve a `nodeList` you index into to get the item of interest.

As you only want part of the information retrieved you can use `split` to "slice" out the required info. Note that `Kit` is not `Kit` alone but is `Kit (CD117)`.

---

### XMLHTTPRequest XHR:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument, arr() As String, ele As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:D01441", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ele = .querySelectorAll(".td51 div")(6)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        arr = Split(ele.innerText, Chr$(10))
    End With
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print Split(arr(i), "[")(0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

### Internet Explorer:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, arr() As String, ele As Object, i As Long

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:D01441"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ele = html.querySelectorAll(".td51 div")(6)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  
        arr = Split(ele.innerText, Chr$(10))

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print Split(arr(i), "[")(0)
        Next i
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References:**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

### EDIT:

This has become rather long but following our debugging to merge with your other code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ht()
    Dim ie As Object, ele As Object, i As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rawString() As String, rowIndex As Long
    Dim arrayOfValues() As Variant, html As HTMLDocument, arr() As String
    Const URL As String = "https://www.genome.jp/kegg/drug/"
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row
    arrayOfValues = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
            .navigate URL
            Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            rawString = VBA.Strings.Split(VBA.Strings.LCase$(arrayOfValues(rowIndex, 1)), ": ", -1, vbBinaryCompare)

            'MsgBox rawString(1)
            .document.querySelector("input[name=q]").Value = rawString(1)
            .document.querySelector("input[value=Go]").Click

            Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Dim ele2 As Object
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele2 = .document.querySelector("a[href^='/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ele2 Is Nothing Then GoTo NextLink
            ele2.Click

            Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Set html = .document
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = html.querySelectorAll(".td51 div")(6)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                arr = Split(ele.innerText, Chr$(10))
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    Debug.Print Split(arr(i), "[")(0)
                Next i
            End If
NextLink:
        Next rowIndex
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And there's no way to search for the <nobr> tag that has "Target" within using queryselection or otherwise?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to get to the CSS Query like you did in your post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177672/discussion-between-qharr-and-user90823745).