# Web scraping text in a table

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I want all the text content from the website's table into Excel cells A9 to A16. Cells A1 to A8 is fine as all the data is there but the formatting is bad (another issue).

I'm using `.getElementByClassName` and the table's class name is table and it's the first table in the site hence the 0. I'm trying to get all text content in the tr tags but it is not populating completely starting at A9. I assume there's a lot of spaces in between or another column.

```vb
Sub VBAWebscraping()

    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate Url:="https://www.miamidade.gov/Apps/PA/propertysearch/#/?folio=0431070030890"
    
    Do While ieObj.Busy = True Or ieObj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Loop
    
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
        End With
    
        i = i + 1
    
    Next htmlEle
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any error showing when it doesn't complete from A9? Which IE verison and OS version are you using? I made tests in two versions of IE and found the results are different. In version 11.1082.18362.0, the code works well [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPwMi.gif). But in version 11.572.19041.0, the website even can't load completely and [can't find the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1scN.png) `#property_info`. So please also use F12 dev tools to check the html elements to see if the table has loaded completely.

Comment: Hello Yu Zhou. Thank you for replying. I don't receive any error. I'm using IE Version 11.9 and Windows 10 Pro is my OS. I started looking into other ways to scrape this website and I went down the rabbit hole with Python and API and JSONs. I'm a beginner so I'm still learning and trying to figure it out. I believe the website has completely loaded.

Comment: It's so strange that it doesn't show any error but doesn't work. Your code can work well on my side. It's a good idea that you try to use other ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`i` needs to be initialised with value 9. You could also also iterate over `getElementById("#property_info").rows` rather than returning an entire table collection and indexing into it.

For the tidying, this is because you are extracted the contents of each first child node which may be the parent of various other nodes which, whilst tidy on the page, looks messy without the html formatting in the sheet. You would need to write something more detailed, in terms of the child nodes.

You could also either using data > tools > web query to pull the table (expensive), or
[use the clipboard to transfer the `.outerHTML` of the table to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938256/6241235) where you would use `clipboard.SetText ie.document.getElementById("#property_info").outerHTML`

Comment: Hello QHarr. Thank you for replying. I set i to 9 but all it did was move the data down from A9 to A24. In regards to using the clipboard to transfer the table. I will look into this and get back to you. I've been looking into other ways of scraping and came across APIs, JSONs, etc. It seems like this might be the best way to go about it. Not sure yet.